# border-collapse in table not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, border

I'm needing to collapse a table and it's not working for me.  I'm using inline styling in WordPress because it's just one page that will be styled like this.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;  max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #299696; margin: 0 auto; ">
        <div style="float: right !important; width: 40%; padding-left: 5%;">
          <img style="float: right !important; width: 100%; height: auto; min-width: 325px;" alt="weeSpring parent panel, boy holding apple with heart-shaped bite out of it" src="http://blog.weespring.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/43b6e465b5d42899675508a8d0bc0b36-300x220.jpg"
          />
        </div>
        <div style="float: left !important; width 10%; padding: 6% 1% 0 1%;">
          <img style="float: left !important; width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="" src="http://www.weespring.com/media/disclosure-arrow.png" />
        </div>
        <h5 style="color: #ffffff !important; padding-top: 2%;">Disclosure Statement from weeSpring</h5>
        <p style="color: #ffffff !important; font-size: 14px; margin: 0 5% 0 6%; text-align: left !important; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.4em;"><span style="font-size: 28px;">O</span>n weeSpring, members may be invited to participate in sampling campaigns where they receive complimentary products for review. When posting their reviews, members are required to abide by our disclosure terms:</p>
        <p></p>
        <p style="color: #ffffff !important; font-size: 14px; margin: 0 5% 0 6%; text-align: left !important; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.4em;">The Federal Trade Commission requires testing program participants to disclose that they have received products for complimentary testing purposes in all review materials. Please note that failure to abide by these rules may result in suspension
          from the weeSpring Parent Panel. Please refer to the following rules and guidelines below for more information.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%; background-color: #000000; vertical-align: middle;">
        <span style="color: #299696 !important; font-size: 1.8em; font-weight: bold;">When Writing Reviews</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The border-collapse is working..see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/vL64mkzt/)

Comment: Yes, like @Lal says border-collapse is OK. If you mean the space outside the table, this is browser default `margin` of the `body`, so you must use some reset css for this.

Comment: Yes, works fine. If you add border: 3px solid black; you will see only one line not two.

Comment: So weird...it's not working when I preview it in WP.  Maybe a browser issue? I'm in Chrome. [link] (http://screencast.com/t/4UZGCVeoc)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like all I had to do to solve this was add this to my table cell style and oddly, it solved it.
    `border: solid 0;`